# responsive live streaming player projekktor

Tags: html, streaming, projekktor

Hi im trying to make the video player responsive heres my code:

```
    <!-- Load projekktor css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/maccaco/projekktor.style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- Load jquery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- load projekktor js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="projekktor-1.4.00-test.js"></script>    </head>
<body>

    <div id="player_a" class="projekktor">
        <noscript><p>No JavaScript support.</p></noscript>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            projekktor('#player_a', {

              controls: true,
              autoplay: true,
              title: 'Projekktor - Inline HLS video support',
              playerFlashMP4: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback_hls_mss.swf',
                playerFlashMP3: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback /StrobeMediaPlayback_hls_mss.swf',
                width: 640,
                height: 385,
                platforms: ['browser', 'ios', 'android', 'flash', 'native'],
                playlist: [     
                    {
                    0: {src: "http://ip:1935/videostreaming/videostreaming/playlist.m3u8", type: "application/mpegURL", streamType: "httpVideo"}, // your HLS manifest goes here
                    1: {src: "", type: "video/mp4", streamType: "http"} // you can even add progressive fallback
                    }
          ]    
            }
            );
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

when i put width : 100% and height 100% the video dissapears but i have sound how i can fix this.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well if that was a typo..

Best bet to mod it using the debugger. There are quite a lot of dependencies here.

Comment: oh no that was a typo mistake

Comment: Are the parameters in the js correct to take % and not px? Try modding it using the chrome debugger. Thats my best bet..